# Computing $P(X<Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

let X,Y two independent discret Random Variables. $P(X=i)$ and $P(Y=i) $are given. 
I want to calculate $P(X< Y)$, so

$$P(X<Y)=P(X-Y<0)= \sum P(x-Y<0,X=x)=\sum P(x<Y)P(X=x)=\sum (1-P(Y \le x))P(X=x)=\sum(1-\sum P(Y=i))P(X=x)$$
where the inner sum goes from $i=1$ to $i=x$ and the outer sum over all outcomes from X. I this correct? Here I substituted X=x, theoretically i could substitute Y=y too. would the outcome be the same?

Comment: Indeed, if $X$ and $Y$ are positive and integer valued, $P(X<Y)$ is $$\sum_{j=2}^\infty P(Y=j)\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}P(X=i)$$ which is also $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X=i)\sum_{j=i+1}^\infty P(Y=j)$$ which is also $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X=i)\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^i P(Y=j)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. was a bit confused here.